# How apply where only a column is not null in adonis query builder

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I need to check if the column `percentage_correct` >= `parCorrect` if `percentage_correct` <> NULL

I try something like:

```
const unidadeSequenceAtualEstudante = await Database.select("*")
            .from("student_quiz_historics")
            .where("student_id", idEstudante)
            .where(function(){
                this
                .whereNotNull("percentage_correct")
                .where("percentage_correct", ">=", parQtdAcerto)
            })
            .where("class_id", idClasse)
            .where("book_id", idLivro)
            .where("execution_back_status", "<>", "Cancelado")
            .orderBy("sequence", "desc")
            .first();
```

But when i have only records with the `percentage_correct` null, they still are trying to apply this where.

Comment: can you provide https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little trouble replicating your problem. What you have there should work, but it's possible you're not considering something about SQL's behaviour with regard to NULL: *anything* compared to NULL is NULL, which is why the `IS NOT NULL` syntax exists. So for example:

```
foo=# SELECT 1 >= NULL;
?column?
----------
NULL
(1 row)

foo=# SELECT NULL >= 1;
?column?
----------
NULL
(1 row)
```

This means that you can kind of get away with not checking for the null at all, because only rows that meet the condition will be returned:

```
const unidadeSequenceAtualEstudante = await Database.select("*")
  .from("student_quiz_historics")
  .where({
    book_id: idLivro,
    class_id: idClasse,
    student_id: idEstudante
  })
  .where('percentage_correct', '>=', parQtdAcerto)
  .where("execution_back_status", "<>", "Cancelado")
  .orderBy("sequence", "desc")
  .first();
```

Is this a good idea? Debatable. I think it's probably fine for this purpose, but we shouldn't assume that `NULL` is the same thing as `FALSE`, because it isn't.

If you're still having trouble with your query, you'd need to provide more details about which database you're using, what your schema is and what kind of errors your getting.